# Execute Java example after test and package with Maven

Tags: java, maven, compilation, execute

I am trying to run my first Java program, an example script that interacts with a online API ([source](https://github.com/nesstar/nesstar-api-demo) on Github).

As it has dependencies, I follow the recommended steps using `mvn test` and `mvn package`, which seem to work (see [output](http://pastie.org/4251039)).

I however do not understand how to run the program that I just compiled (or packaged?). The `.java` file contains `public final class NesstarStudyLister`, so based on the `pom.xml` file I try (in the base directory) the following command:

`mhermans@fyr:~/tmp/nesstar-api-demo$ java -cp target/nesstar_study_lister-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.nesstar.demo.NesstarStudyLister`

Which [results](http://pastie.org/4251058) in a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

How can I successfully run the small Java-program?

**EDIT**:

Based on the recommendation of Dave Newton, I used the [Exec Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), which apparently simply consists of running

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.nesstar.demo.NesstarStudyLister
```

in the base directory, which flawlessly executes the java program.

The solution by Andriy Plokhotnyuk also works, using these commands:

```
(edit pom.xml to include the <build>...</build> information)
mvn package
java -jar target/nesstar_study_lister-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easiest* way is generally the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Nutshell:

- Add the exec plugin as a dependency.
- Define the main class attribute (your program's entry point).
- Run the exec goal.

You may also use Maven to create a directory with your project's dependencies (jars) and set the classpath manually, but IMO that's kind of a pain when you can use the plugin.

You may also create a jar that *includes* all your project's dependencies in a single file, but this may require a bit more work to explicitly include/exclude any conflicting dependencies. (With the caveat that this may be an issue with either other method as well.)

Answer (score 2):

Add following plugin configuration to prepare executable jar:

```xml
 <project>
 ....   
   <build>
       <plugins>    
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.nesstar.demo.NesstarStudyLister</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

       </plugins>
   </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then goto the target directory and run:

```
java -jar nesstar_study_lister-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an executable jar file and then use java -jar filedirectory/fileName.jar

Comment: I believe that's essentially what the OP is doing, based on the command line provided. It'd also require the proper manifest to be generated/packaged.